# Can I disable Query Designer in Visual Studio in favor of plain SQL editor with highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, server-explorer, query-designer

I hate the standard **Query Designer** window that comes up when you select **New Query** on a data connection in Server Explorer. I'd much rather have a T-SQL Editor come up. Is this possible?

Maybe not replace that functionality but a shortcut key or something that would bring up a T-SQL editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround, although it does not solve the problem completely:

1. Open **Tools > Customize > Commands**
2. Select **Context menu: Other Context Menus | Server Explorer**
3. Remove annoying **New Query**
4. Click **Add Command...**
5. Locate **Data > New Query Connection...**
6. Click **OK** to add it to Server Explorer context menu

This adds **New Query Connection...** context menu to all **Server Explorer** connections (as well as the root **Data Connections** item):

[image: New Query Connection menu]

This will fire up the T-SQL Editor.

**The only problem with this workaround is that, invoked this way, T-SQL Editor has no way of  knowing which connection was selected so it asks for connection settings again.** You will also have to specify the database in the toolbar (easy if you're working with just one).

Although it's not perfect, I find it a better solution that constantly hitting the Query Designer awkwardness.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012 this command is found under the SQL category as "New Query..." (substitute in step 5)

Comment: I hate the Query Designer with a passion. Thank-you for this

Answer (score 9):

Tools > Options > Database Tools > Query and View Designers > Panes shown by default

Uncheck the **Diagram** and **Criteria** (and **Results** if you want even more clean look)

[image]