# How can I stop Visual Studio 2019 from editing queries?

Tags: visual-studio

When running some SQL commands like `select`, the query itself changes. For example, the query `select * from co_user` becomes

```sql
SELECT        rowid, 'time', 'user', uuid
FROM            co_user
```

Is there a way to disable this or must I change how I connect to my database?

I have tried googling the answer but the best thing I found was: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915356/can-i-disable-query-designer-in-visual-studio-in-favor-of-plain-sql-editor-with#:~:text=Tools%20>%20Options%20>%20Database%20Tools%20>%20Query,Results%20if%20you%20want%20even%20more%20clean%20look%29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915356/can-i-disable-query-designer-in-visual-studio-in-favor-of-plain-sql-editor-with#:%7E:text=Tools%20%3E%20Options%20%3E%20Database%20Tools%20%3E%20Query,Results%20if%20you%20want%20even%20more%20clean%20look%29)

Comment: Run how? In what window or file? Visual Studio doesn't reformat queries by itself and certainly not like that